# Compiz reverts to desktop wall

Tags: compiz

I installed compiz and when I enter `compiz --replace` in terminal after switching compiz from desktop wall to desktop cube the cube works and rotates. However, when I exit terminal compiz reverts back to the desktop wall and disabled the desktop cube.

When I try to use lillypad or gedit to change the string value from `xwfm4` to `compiz` it will not save the change. I apologize if this has been asked before but if it has any links to resolved questions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which desktop environment do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Putting an `&` at the end of the command line is detached from the shell and the program continues in the background even though quitting the shell.
Try this:

```
compiz --replace &
exit
```

type `compiz --help` or `man compiz` for more options.

Comment: Tired the compiz  --replace & exit compiz just frozE eh this computer is just like a bigger version of my old computer why can't things just work the same